# "__init__" looks so ugly in Python. Is there another way to code this construct?

Tags: python

I have used this in my code, but "underscore underscore init underscore underscore" looks so ugly in Python, because it is not clear at a glance as to whether these prefixes and suffixes are one, two or three characters. Is there another way to code this construct without the double underscore? For example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar(self)
```

Annoyingly this code does not work, so obviously the underscore plays an essential role:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField()
    def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).init(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar(self)
```

What is the purpose of this syntax?

Comment: Change your font to get good looking underscores ?

Comment: Why is it ugly? If double underscore names are not your thing, Python might not be the language for you.

Comment: And yes, the name of the initialiser method is `__init__`. The underscores are part of the name. Python uses the pattern for all hook methods and internal attributes, because these are easy to keep separate from user-defined names.

Comment: Yeah, I way prefer C++. But Python is useful for web stuff.

Comment: Have some ancestor class which has an `__init__()` method which just punts to `init()`.

Comment: The answer to the "purpose" of this syntax can be found by a simple web search (or see @MartijnPieters comment above). But are you asking for a way to avoid `__init__` altogether while still having classes? Would you go so far as to make namespaces and attach attributes one by one?

Comment: So it's for people that can't remember what are the keywords in the language. I'm sorry but I find that really lame and don't understand why so many negative votes.  Obviously SO is not the place to discuss this kind of topic.

Comment: Get used to it. You might as well complain about the color of the company bike shed for all the good trying to change this would do.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're being downvoted.  This is not a bad question.

Comment: No, it's not for people that "can't remember" what the keywords are. It's part of the language specification. Why is it such a big deal, anyway?

Comment: @wim: It seems more like an excuse to complain than a real question, especially with the insulting comments and the implication that the OP is here to start a discussion.

Comment: I feel like this should be closed [...]?

Comment: It is not obvious to read two underscores: is it one, two or three.  But if I remove them from my code I get an error.

Comment: It is valid. He is not a sole person who thinks underscores in `__init__` are ugly. Google `python underscore ugly`, then you will find thousands of articles saying that such thing is ugly. *Beautiful is better than ugly*? How did it become the **first** principle in Zen of Python with `__init__`? If it were just one underscore, that is not bad, but *two underscores*? Can people see how many underscores in `__` or `___` at first glance?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another way to code this construct without the double underscore?

No, that's part of the Python object model directly:

[`https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)

You can not change this without recompiling your own Python interpreter.

> What is the purpose of this syntax?

The double underscore "dunder" is there to indicate a method which has special meaning in the object model.  In time you will get used to it and may even begin to like it.  When reading code, it provides an easy way to visually distinguish the Python datamodel "hooks" in any 3rd-party code.

Comment: Right, it sounds to me like it was just added for people who are too lazy to learn the keywords in the language?

Comment: Not really.  The [keywords](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7b909a93bf8dfa4b81d0d6bdb0611418d41d507b/Lib/keyword.py#L15-L51) are something different.  Since you said you prefer C++, you could think of the dunders as Python's way of providing access to operator overloading, amongst other things.

Answer (score 1):

Although I completely agree with @wim's answer, you can achieve what you want by using a decorator:

```
def custom_init(name='init'):
    def wrapper(callable):
        if not hasattr(callable, name):
            raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found on {}'.format(name, callable))
        callable.__init__ = getattr(callable, name)
        return callable
    return wrapper
```

You would then just:

```
@custom_init(name='foo')
class SomeClass(object):
    def foo(self, some_value):
        self.value = some_value

c = SomeClass(42)
print(c.value) # Prints 42
```

Of course, for derived classes, you just need to remember to call `__init__` on the base class:

```
@custom_init()
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField()
    def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar(self)
```